# How to name multiple entities returned from a Query Handler?

Tags: php, naming, cqrs

I've got the following flow:

[image: Function flow]

HTTP API is exposing data from 2 database tables that are combined into one JSON structure. We're implementing this using CQRS - splitting the reads from multiple tables into different queries to run in parallel. Since the language we're using is PHP and it doesn't currently support multiple returns or any other easy structures (that I'm aware of) - I am trying to come up with a name for a "composite structure" that would encapsulate 2 or more Entities.

I would really like to use a name that's fitting (maybe from other languages?) or even think of a better way to package the data to send it back to the service? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered `FooSettings`?

Comment: I have, the problem is I would like to have a name that's reusable for different kinds of actions in the domain. So in the same way as we're calling `findSettings` there will be `sendInvoice` `calculateRate` and these will be coming back as a composition of multiple Entities. One idea was to use `BusinessObject` e.g. `SettingsBusinessObject`, `RateBusinessObject` but that feels overly verbose.